# Как добавить вход/выход из сделки на бирже Mexc в боте на Python?

Tags: python, бот

Всем привет, создаю бота для автоматической торговли на платформе Mexc, и у меня возникла проблема, как автоматически реализовать покупку и продажу на Python, если выполняются условия для входа в сделку, а потом выполняются для выхода из сделки.
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

По этой теме я нашел только данный ресурс https://mxcdevelop.github.io/apidocs/spot_v3_en/#new-order но мне не понятно, например что такое timestamp и type.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.